# Reverse piezo effect of quartz and quartz-rich rock

Tags: piezoelectric

If quartz or quartz-rich rock vibrates when used as a conductor (electrostriction), would it grind away when pushed against an immovable object with enough force? How much force?

Comment: This seems to be an [engineering.se] problem more than a physics one. If you post there, be sure to include more details such as the exact dimensions and shape of the crystal, the direction and frequency of the "vibration" relative to the crystalline lattice orientation, the shear strength of the crystal and all other relevant details. I expect you may find the wave is reflected so that it creates additional wave fronts and reinforced peaks of stress within the crystalline structure, leading it to shatter before wearing away.

Comment: "If quartz or quartz-rich rock **vibrates** when used as a conductor (electrostriction)".  Well, no and no.  No, quartz (at least pure quartz) isn't ever a conductor, and no, it doesn't necessarily vibrate.  Quartz generates an internal electric field proportional to the amount that it is strained, and it generates an internal strain proportional to an applied electric field.  If all you do is apply a field to quartz it will change it's dimensions slightly, but it will only _vibrate_ to the degree that it is mechanically resonant, and that resonance has been excited.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.